# Flutter NoSuchMethodError: The method 'listen' was called on null

Tags: flutter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de hacer un registro en mi app android con flutter, pero al momento dar al boton de registrar me muestra este error y me señala el metodo que muestro acontinuacion, estoy usando postgres, node , y el backend con js.

Agradezco a quien me pueda ayudar !!!

Error

**Exception has occurred.
Nosuchmethoderror (NosuchMethodError: The method 'listen' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: listen(Closure: (dynamic) => Null))**

```
   stream.listen((res) {
      _progressDialog.close();
      ResponseApi responseApi = ResponseApi.fromJson(json.decode(res));
      print('RESPUESTA: ${responseApi.toJson()}');
      MySnackbar.show(context, responseApi.message);

      if (responseApi.success) {
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'login');
        });
      } else {
        isEnable = true;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el error como texto y no como imagen, asi es más facil ayudarte

Comment: ahí te dice que `stream` es nulo